# NSClassFromString in library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dynamic

I have 2 projects.

The first project is a Cocoa Touch Static Library.
The other is a iPad application project.

In my library project i make a call to get a class and make an instance from it:

```
NSClassFromString(@"ClassName");
```

The only problem is, this will return nil.
In my main iPad application project, this will not return nil.

The class which it should load from the string is in the iPad project.

My explanation would be, the library cannot load the class, because it is not in it's bundle.
Is this true?

How would i solve this problem, so the call in the library will not return nil?

Thanks

Comment: Is the class actually defined in the static library or in the iPad project?

Comment: In the iPad project. Just edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My explanation would be, the library cannot load the class, because it
>   is not in it's bundle. Is this true?

No, not true. At runtime there are no Libraries, no Projects, just your App, containing all (your) linked code, which is all in your executable.

You could be doing it before Classes have loaded, you could have spelt it wrong, you would have to show some code.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing a specific class in your static library that is not defined in the library kinda defeats the purpose of having a static library in the first place, since it creates coupling between the library and the code utilizing that library.

If your library requires a class not defined in it, you should consider changing your API to ask for the class name rather than assume a particular one:

```
- (void)doSomething {
  klass = NSClassFromString(@"ClassName");
  obj = [[klass alloc] init];
  [obj doSomething];
  [obj release];
}

- (void)doSomethingWithNewObjectFromClass:(Class)klass {
  obj = [[klass alloc] init];
  [obj doSomething];
  [obj release];
}
```

Preferably, you should consider using the [delegate pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18).

Comment: I see your point of the problem that a library has knowledge of implementation that is using the library. In my project that is not the case. The library only holds class object (dont ask me why). I figured i had to pass the actual class as parameter, but i had rather loaded it from strings. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The project should config the "other linker flag" (OTHER_LDFLAGS) to add value "-ObjC".

Answer (score 0):

I am adding the same in AppDelegate and reading application class.
let moduleName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"] as! String
let personClass: AnyClass? = NSClassFromString(moduleName + "." + "TMTServicePresenter")

Its working. But same time If lib file "TelemetrySFService" its failing.

let personClass: AnyClass? = NSClassFromString(moduleName + "." + "TelemetrySFService"